# Optimization in python with soft constraint inside the objective function

Tags: python, optimization

I am looking for a way to have constraints that occur inside the objective function. In the below example, how would an internal soft constraint in the array_var be defined?

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint,     NonlinearConstraint

#initial guess of the variable:
x0 = [10, 10]

#Variable limits:
bounds = ((0, 10), (0, 20))

def objective_function(x):
    #create a data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')) 

    #create dataframe calculations
    df2 = df*x[0] + x[1]
    
    #use data frame to calculate a numpy array
    array_var = np.array(df.loc[1])

    #calculate objective variable that needs minimization
    objective = df2.sum()

    return(objective)
 
#optimization method:
result = minimize(objective_function, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds)
```

---

soft constraint: all 4 array_var elements be below a threshold, i.e. array_var < 3

I tried this:

---

```
def constraints_fun(x):
    #create a data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    
    #create dataframe calculations
    df2 = df*x[0] + x[1]

    #use data frame to calculate a numpy array
    array_var = np.array(df.loc[1])

    return(array_var - 0.3)

#constraints
constraints = ({'type':'ineq','fun':constraints_fun})

#minimize function
result = minimize(objective_function, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

print('Optimization result:')
print('Status:', result.message)
print('Solution:', result.x)
print('Objective value:', result.fun
```

---

Is it possible to have the constrain inside the objective_function? This would make it more efficient by not having the dataframe calculated twice. I tried this with scipy library but any other nonlinear optimization package or solver is welcome.

Comment: Try applying the constraint inside the objective function, without setting it in `minimize()`. For example, if the constraint is that `array_var` must be between 0 and 1, then inside `objective` you could have a line that says `array_var = array_var.clip(0, 1)`. You can replace this with a more complex constraint with the `contraint()` function you've defined. I haven't tried this in scipy, but I've seen a similar approach taken in an ML library and perhaps it can generalise to your case. Should be relatively simple to give it a quick trial.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The [np.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) function pins the values to predetermined numbers. The example here needs some soft (penalty) be defined.

Comment: Something like `penalty = 10 * (array_var > threshold).sum()` would add a penalty of 10 for each element of `array_var` that exceeds `threshold`. If you wanted a smoother penalty than simply 0/10 per element, you could penalise based on how far above the threshold the elements are: `penalty = (array_var - threshold).abs().sum()` or `penalty = (array_var - threshold)**2.sum()`. I think the penalty definition can be of your choosing, as long as the model is incentivised to minimise it (sign matters). Finally, add `penalty` to `objective` & return. This should cause the model to minimise both.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a good idea, although the human has to decide about the penalty.

Comment: No problem. L1 or L2-style penalties are quite common; they simply either take the absolute sum of something, or the square. But you might have reasons to make a penalty more complex.